# Mysql statement doesnt work with jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

my connection with DB is good this line of code works fine:

```
//res=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT UzID FROM uzsakymas");
```

but this doesnt:

```
res=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT UzID FROM uzsakymas inner join klientas on uzsakymas.KlientID=klientas.KlientID and klientas.vardas='Ramūnas' and klientas.KlientID='1'");
```

i tryed pasting it into phpmyadmin query and it worked fine too

so my connection with db is good, statement is good, why the hell it doesnt work? :/

Comment: Not working how... throws an error? returns no results?

Comment: doesnt return anything in jsp

Comment: There is really not enough to go on here... what does the code that processes the result look like?

Comment: I suspect it's an issue with a characterset translation (the character that looks like a u with a line over it is the likely suspect). As a test, try `.vardas LIKE 'Ram%nas'`  Also, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'`.  I suspect that the connection you have from JSP has a different character set setting than your phpmyadmin. Also verify that both connections are as the same user to the same database.

Comment: thank you spencer, you really helped, that was the error :)